# Unable to set a bridge over bonding on Debian

Tags: networking, debian, bridge, bonding

I have a Debian 8 Jessie machine with two interfaces (eth0 and eth1) bonded in balance-rr mode (aka 0). It works smoothly, but when I try to set up a bridge on it, it doesn't work.

My /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    slaves eth0 eth1
    bond-mode 0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond_downdelay 200
    bond_updelay 200

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.20.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.20.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    bridge_ports bond0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_stp off
```

Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Show us logs `tail -f /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog /var/log/dmesg &` and do `service networking restart` .

Answer (score 1):

This is working config from my server:

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    up ifconfig bond0 0.0.0.0 up
    slaves eth1 eth0
    bond-mode 0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.162.235
    netmask 255.255.192.0
    gateway 192.168.150.254
    bridge_ports bond0 vnet0
    bridge_stp off # switch on with more system like this
    bridge_maxage 0
    bridge_ageing 0
    bridge_ageing 0
```

Besides that you need to install:

```
 apt-get install bridge-utils ifenslave
```

Remove any bond module configuration from /etc/modprobe.d/

Comment: +1 Note that OP's mistake was having the bond interface as `static` without an address. Also, you can replace the ifconfig with iproute2 (preferred):  `up ip link set up dev bond0`.

Answer (score 1):

It was working fine for me also with `bond-mode 5` (lacp) and the `ip` command suggested in one of the comments:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    up ip link set up dev bond0
    slaves eth1 eth0
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.162.235
    netmask 255.255.192.0
    gateway 192.168.150.254
    bridge_ports bond0
    bridge_stp off # switch on with more system like this
    bridge_maxage 0
    bridge_ageing 0
```

Anyway all credit goes to [Michal Sokolowski](https://serverfault.com/users/259376/michal-sokolowski).

Answer (score 0):

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
     up ip link set up dev bond0
    bond-mode 5
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 0
    bond-slaves enp3s0 enp2s0

auto virbr0
iface virbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.3
    gateway 192.168.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 192.168.10.2 192.168.10.1
    bridge_ports bond0
    dns-search yoyo.yo
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge maxwait 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add the line:

```
pre-up sleep 2
```

to bridge configuration.